# Marketplace Assign Products quantity is not working

Tags: magento

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site. we gave an option for seller to update the product information through frontend.

seller A uploaded product A in frontend [quantity = 20 ]

if seller B have same product , he will assign the same product to his account [quantity = 5 ]

here updating seller B, Means assigned seller Quantity is not working.

i am using following code for editing assign quantity , but its not saving in database.

```
<span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>
    </span>

    <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name="stock" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>" style="display:none;"/>

    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>

    <p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>

    <button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
        <span>
            <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>

    <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none"></button>
```

**script**

```
function hideReset(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).hide();
        $wk_jq(editLink).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
    }

    function showField(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        return false;
    }

    function updateField(product_id,assignqty)
    {
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var valueId         = '#valueqty_'+ product_id;
        var updatedqty      = '#updatedqty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
        var url             = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

        $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
        jQuery(valueId).html($qty);
        hideReset(product_id);

        var tmpQty = assignqty+parseInt($qty) ;

        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {id: product_id, qty: tmpQty},
            onComplete: function (transport) {
                jQuery(priceId).val($price);                
        jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Good Question I am also looking for it's solution because i want to know it's possible in magento or not. I am flag this question for moderation thanks baby for asking this question.

Comment: @ShakirKhan are you using any marketplace extension?

Comment: yes i have develop two and also have paid one

Comment: thats great , are yu using the webkul marketplace assign product extension